# XML parse problem with $xml->formatOutPut

Tags: php, javascript, xml

I recently learned how to format the output with simpleXML in PHP. You just add the line `$xml->formatOutPut = true;` But when I did it, the javascripts that I have written cannot parse the XML. I use to opt out the formatOutPut line, so the XML are written unformatted in one line. When I opt out the format line the javascript can parse the XML. Really wierd. Is there a way to not opt out the format line in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you parse the XML with javascript?
If the problem is the formatted output, I guess you use methods/collections which also handle textNodes (childNodes for example). If that's the case you have to modify your javascript in that way, that it will skip textNodes that only contain whiteSpaces(jQuery for example could do this for you).

Comment: I parse the XML with "var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;". and use the getElementsByTagName() method to get all the nodes. So you say that the whiteSpaces are causing the error? Can you give some methods in javascripts to solve this problem? I don't want to use JQuery

Comment: getElementsByTagName shouldn't have problems with withespaces, it only handles element-nodes. Can you show your javascript-parser to determine the problem?

Comment: xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.open("GET","serverScripts/contacts/showContactList.php",false);
 xmlhttp.send();
 
 var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
 var root = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('contacts');

Then I get the XMl nodeValue through this javascript codes. The first line that fails is:
.
.
.





var profileId = root[0].childNodes[i].getAttribute('profileId');
  var profileMiniature = root[0].childNodes[i].getAttribute('profileMiniature');

Comment: is it the childNodes[0] that causes the problem? Because there are some whitespaces?

Comment: @Dr.Molle: It was the childNodes[0] that cause the errors. I think I will fix the problem now. But thanks for your help

Comment: yes, childNodes causes the error. Use children instead, it will only return childNodes that are elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.children